# What is the best resource to deploy a .Net Core WebAPI in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

As the title implies, I am developing a .Net core WebAPI app and am wondering if there is a better resource (there are so damn many now) that a basic **Web App** to deploy my WebAPI?  Any input is greatly appreciated, as you know the MS docs are sometimes a bit frustrating!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I disagree @JanDvorak, in the Azure world, there is generally a 'best' way, it is just difficult to locate.

Comment: Please read [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/243450) before attempting to ask more questions that are opinion based that invite argumentative discussion because they do not have a single agreed upon answer.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Asking what the best practice is might be doable. Asking where the best practice is documented is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the an [API App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-apps-why-best-platform) for your WebAPI. A Web App usually contains web *content* e. g. HTML, JavaScript.

Comment: Well, nowadays the only differences between Web and API apps are the logo and name :) I would also use an API app though just because it tells me that it's an API.

Comment: @juunas True, I am also not aware of any differences in provided features. But maybe that will change in the future.

Comment: Perfect - so many damn services in the list I somehow missed this one!  Thank you.